# Issue with the Textarea Readonly when using "wysihtml5" of bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, wysihtml5

I have tried to make the text area readonly in MVC4 Application.

But it is always being enable to edit when i use below code:

```
   @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.EndUserHelp, new { id = "name1", @class = "editorHelp"})

$('#name1').wysihtml5({
                "font-styles": true,
                "emphasis": true, 
                "lists": true, 
                "html": false, 
                "link": true, 
                "image": true,
                "color": false, 
                "useLineBreaks": true
            });
   $("#name1").prop('readonly', true);
```

unable to make the area readonly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the following code where you initialize the editor.
I had the same issue with version 0.3.0 and made this to fix it.

```
function enforceInactiveStates() {
    var disabled = this.textareaElement.disabled;
    var readonly = !!this.textareaElement.getAttribute('readonly');

    if (readonly) {
        this.composer.element.setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
        this.toolbar.commandsDisabled = true;
    }

    if (disabled) {
        this.composer.disable();
        this.toolbar.commandsDisabled = true;
    }
}
editor.on( 'load', enforceInactiveStates );
```

Note that 'readonly' is different from 'disabled'.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$editor = $(".textarea-disabled").wysihtml5();
$editor.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Use `'disabled'` not `'readonly'`